# Excel 2016 count unique values in a range based on more than one range

Tags: excel-formula

I am attempting to count the number of unique occurrences of an order number between a given date range, which i have successfully achieved using the code below ;

Column A = Date

Column B = Order Number

Cell W3 = From Date

Cell X3 = To Date

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF((A$2:A$10000<=X3)*(A$2:A$10000>=W3),
1/COUNTIFS(A$2:A$10000, "<="&X3,A$2:A$10000, ">="&W3,
B$2:B$10000,B$2:B$10000), 0))}
```

My issue is that i want to add another crietria which is held in Column U, that value being 'F' for arguments sake. I have tried to break this formula into bite size chunks to understand exactly what it is doing, but it is beyond me.

[image]

As you can see from the screen shot, there are 7 unique order numbers between the date range shown in Cell W3 to Cell X3 the result showing in Cell Y3 as per my formula.

I wish to add another formula that counts the same dataset with any row that has the value of 'F' in column U the result would be 1 as per cell Z3 highlighted in red, which i have manually entered.

Can anyone advise please.

Comment: Please provide some sample data in Column A, B, U, and Cell W3, X3, and indicate the expected output and the logic behind.

Comment: Thanks Terry, i have added a screen shot and explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach using methods from this article: [Count unique values among duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **DateList** being data in your date column;
- **OrderList** being data in your order number column;
- **Col_U** being the column that holds your extra criteria;
- **FromD** being the *From Date*;
- **ToD** being the *To Date*.

Use the following formula to return the unique count of order number in the given date range and criteria **F**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(OrderList*(DateList>=FromD)*(DateList<=ToD)*(Col_U="F"),OrderList*(DateList>=FromD)*(DateList<=ToD)*(Col_U="F"))>0))-1
```

[image: Solution]

> The difficult part is to understand the methodology of finding the **filtered** range using this equation `=OrderList*(DateList>=FromD)*(DateList<=ToD)*(Col_U="F")`.
>
> then use `FREQUENCY(filtered_range,filtered_range)>0` to find out how many order numbers have more than one appearance in the filtered range, and lastly use **SUMPRODUCT** to return the total count. The `-1` at the end of my formula is to taken out the count of duplicated `0` returned in the filtered range.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi Terry, i have never used FREQUENCY , but yes it worked thanks. I need to take a proper look at this function.

Comment: @Prospidnick no worries feel free to ask if there is any question :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Formula in cell H3:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF((A$2:A$10000<=F3)*(A$2:A$10000>=E3)*(C$2:C$10000=G3),
1/COUNTIFS(A$2:A$10000,"<="&F3,A$2:A$10000,">="&E3,C$2:C$10000,"="&G3,
B$2:B$10000,B$2:B$10000), 0))
```

Comment: you probably want to mention the above formula needs to be confirmed by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter :)